# How to manually adjust wrapping topology of netlogo interface?

Tags: netlogo

Netlogo only provides four topology options that dictates what turtles and patches do when they reach the any given edge of the netlogo world or interface, namely, box, torus, horizontal wrapping and vertical wrapping ... Is there a way to adjust these options so that just one edge is wrapped? Or three edges are wrapped for instance?

Comment: What would it mean to have one edge wrapped? What would happen at the other side?

Comment: @LukeC you may not remember me but I remember you very well, you helped me immensely with a couple previous netlogo problems! Anyway, at the other side, they are turtles are reflected back into the world or die!

Comment: So you want them to be able to (for example) walk off the right hand side and appear at the left hand side, but nothing happens if they try and walk left while at the left hand side? Note that not-wrap does not mean they die or reflect now, they simply stop moving any further.

Comment: @JenB that is exactly right, thanks for your help. It would be nice if they could be reflected back in at the left-hand side to keep on walking, and yes, walk through the right hand side and reappear on the left hand side

Comment: There's definitely nothing like that built in. You would have to set up the world with wrapping and then have a wall that only allows movement in one direction. Search for 'walls' in the Models Library to get some ideas about how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nigus- I do remember, I never forget a Corgi! Anyway, as Jen mentioned there is no built-in for this, but you can build it into your turtle movement rules. For example, with this setup:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [ pd ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

If you want your turtles to treat a boundary as closed, you could have them check their `patch-ahead` by whatever their movement speed is (example speed of 1, here) and do a simple math operation to see if they are 'allowed' to wrap at that boundary. To have the left boundary closed, try:

```
to left-closed ; turtle procedure
  ask turtles [ 
    let target patch-ahead 1 
    if  ( ( [pxcor] of target ) - pxcor ) <= 1 [
      fd 1
    ]
  ] 
  tick  
end
```

To have the right boundary closed, you can just do the opposite:

```
to right-closed ; turtle procedure
  ask turtles [ 
    let target patch-ahead 1 
    if  ( pxcor - ( [pxcor] of target ) ) <= 1 [
      fd 1
    ]
  ] 
  tick  
end
```

Obviously, this is a very simple example and would need some work to massage it to fit your current movement rules.

**Edit:**

To show this in action, check out this example code. First, a modified setup that specifies where turtles should spawn and also creates a 'wall' of red patches:

```
to setup
  ca
  ask patches with [ pxcor = 5 ] [
    set pcolor red
  ]
  ask patch -5 0 [
    sprout 10 [
      pd
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Now, a modified version of the `right-closed` procedure above that turns it into a `to-report`:

```
to-report closed-border-right? [ target-patch ]
  report ( pxcor - ( [pxcor] of patch-ahead 1 ) ) <= 1 
end
```

Now, we should expect that turtles should not be able to cross the red wall. They should also not be able to travel off the right border, but they should be able to cross the left border. So, if the turtles are free to wander, using this movement procedure:

```
to move-example
  ask turtles [
    rt random 61 - 30
    let target patch-ahead 1
    if closed-border-right? target and [pcolor] of target != red [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

We should expect them to eventually get 'trapped' between the unwrapped border and the red wall- and this happens as we expect, once the turtles make their way through the left border, they cannot get back:

[image]

Comment: from implementing the above code, it appears the turtles are still able to permeate the left and right boundaries and appear on the opposite side to continue moving instead of reflecting off either boundary back into the world, as though the world is still fully wrapped. Any ideas?

Comment: @nigus21 - Can you explain a bit more? I've edited to provide a working example, so if it isn't doing what you expect please let me know!